# How to prevent customized pfctl's rule is overridden by system?

Tags: pfctl

I add a rule in /etc/pf.conf:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat on utun4 from en5:network to 132.128/9 -> (utun4)  <= this is added
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
```

and load it by "sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf.conf" . after load, "sudo pf.ctl -sn ",
the result is:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
nat-anchor "com.apple/*" all
nat on utun4 inet from 192.160.138.0/24 to 132.128.0.0/9 -> (utun4) round-robin
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*" all
```

but after a while , the added rule is missing , "sudo pf.ctl -sn ",the result is:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
rdr on lo0 inet proto udp from any port != 49978 to 172.16.14.2 port = 53 -> 127.0.0.1 port 5373
```

the rules is overriden by some system automatic operation.

How could I keep this rule all the time , not overriden ?
macOS version is big sur 11.3.1
thks.